# Loop in VBA choosing different sets of data until it sums to X

Tags: excel, vba, loops, optimization, solver

I have a series of data in Excel (280,000 lines) with random values. Each line represents the total ticket of consumptions made in a supermarket branch.

I need to select tickets from those 280,000 lines that add up to USD 1,500,000.

I thought first minimizing errors by using binaries on Solver but the variable limit was too low.

I am thinking of trying with do while / do until. How do I structure this?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object) called `Tickets`. Create a variable to hold the sum, called `Total`. Then you can loop down the sheet, adding tickets to the total and saving the rows in the collection until you reach 1,500,000.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Const STARTING_ROW As Long = 2 'Change this
    Const VALUE_COLUMN As Long = 5 'Change this
    
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet 'Change this
    
    Dim CurrentRow As Range
    Set CurrentRow = DataSheet.Rows(STARTING_ROW)
    
    Dim Tickets As New Collection, Total As Double
    While Total < 1500000
        Tickets.Add CurrentRow
        With CurrentRow.Columns(VALUE_COLUMN)
            If IsNumeric(.Value) Then Total = Total + .Value
        End With

        'Exit condition - End of Sheet
        If CurrentRow.Row = CurrentRow.Parent.Rows.Count Then 
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set CurrentRow = CurrentRow.Offset(1)
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

At the end of this While Loop, you will have all of the ranges inside the `Tickets` collection, whose values sum up to at least 1,500,000.

Comment: Thanks! Then all i need to do is to loop through the items in the collection listing the rows in the next column so I can identify which tickets out of the 280,000 sample have been selected. Correct?

Comment: @lbochitt not quite sure I understand, but yes, you can find all of the Rows inside the collection. They will be Range Objects, so you can do stuff like `Tickets(1).Cells(1,1).Value` to retrieve the value in the first column of the first row in the Tickets collection.

Comment: Hi! Just one more question. How can I list the IDs of all the tickets that add up to the 1.5M? I can't figure out how to do a "for i" within the Tickets collection that gets me the list of the tickets selected.

Comment: An example, assuming ID is in the 3rd column: `For Each Ticket in Tickets: ID = Ticket.Cells(1,3).Value` or as a For Next loop, `For i = 1 to Tickets.Count: ID = Tickets(i).Cells(1,3).Value` This gets you the ID values one by one during the loop. You could then collect them into an array, or a second collection or whatever.